# Truffle SWARM and IPFS Integration

Tags: contract-deployment, truffle, ipfs, swarm

I am now able to use truffle to deploy my contracts in my private blockchain. Now I want to understand how to integrate truffle with SWARM and IPFS for web app deployment. It will be helpful if you could share links giving actual examples this integration showing how to perform these operations.

Comment: did you get an answer to this question?

Comment: Added an answer hope it helps you

Comment: Thank you, let me try this. Giving you an upvote in advance.

Comment: @Sanchit - Were you successful in developing your code to integrate with IPFS via nodejs? If so do share the sample code so that it becomes helpful for everyone else

Answer (score 5):

Watch this demo to setup IPFS node

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8CMxDNuuAiQ

Once Node is setup and you are able to create files in your node and access it then follow these steps.

Command to install the ipfs js library

npm install ipfs --global

Here is the sample code to perform operations on an IPFS node

https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/blob/master/examples/basics/index.js

This is the place where one can find all details for IPFS NodeJS integration

https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs#use-in-nodejs